# npm err to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

I tried to install `npm i react-top-loading-bar` but it showed this error in the terminal.

```
Error: npm err to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution
```

[image]

Comment: Very wild guess. You have more than one React. Please add the deependecies from "package.json"

Comment: That's exactly what is happening, you have react 18 but react-top-loading-bar is a outdated library that requires react 16 or 17